# Yii - CActiveForm client-side not working

Tags: php, forms, validation, yii, submit

I need to validate a form using `CActiveForm` but in client-side.

Here is my code where I initialize the widget and errors:

```
<?php
    $form = $this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(
        'id' => 'idX',
        'enableAjaxValidation' => false,
        'enableClientValidation'=> true,
        'clientOptions'=>array('onSubmit'=>true),
        'htmlOptions' => array(
            'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data'
        ),
    ));
    ?>

<?= $form->errorSummary($model); ?>
```

After this, I have the inputs and in the end I have this:

```
<?php $this->endWidget(); ?>
```

When I submit the form and when I press `F12`(bug inspector in mozilla), the '`jquery.yiiactiveform.js`' is not loaded. This js file is supposed to be included when I use this widget.

-----UPDATED----

```
public function rules() {
    return array(
        //Always required
        array('p_first_name, p_last_name, p_title, p_phone, p_phone2, p_fax, p_email, user, password, clientType', 'required'),
        //just company
        array('c_name, c_postal_code, c_location, c_country, c_activity, c_nif, c_website', 'required', 'on' => 'company'),
        array('c_country, c_activity', 'numerical', 'integerOnly' => true),
        array('c_name, c_location, c_website, p_first_name, p_last_name, p_email', 'length', 'max' => 255),
        array('c_postal_code', 'length', 'max' => 8),
        array('c_nif', 'length', 'max' => 9),
        array('p_title', 'length', 'max' => 25),
        array('p_phone, p_phone2, p_fax', 'length', 'max' => 15),
        array('user, password', 'length', 'max' => 100),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // @todo Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id_client, c_name, c_postal_code, c_location, c_country, c_activity, c_nif, c_website, p_first_name, p_last_name, p_title, p_phone, p_phone2, p_fax, p_email, user, password', 'safe', 'on' => 'search'),
    );
}
```

And one input example:

```
<div class="form-group">
            <?= $form->labelEx($model, 'p_phone', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')); ?>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <?= $form->textField($model, 'p_phone', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => Yii::t('clients/register', 'Insira o contacto telefónico do empresário.'))); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
```

------ UPDATE 2 -------

Now is appearing this error:

TypeError: jQuery(...).yiiactiveform is not a function

Comment: Please provide your inputs and rules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it!

I had two versions of jQuery, so it was causing conflicts. So, if you have, one or two jQuery versions on main.php, remove all!

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss [error](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveForm#error-detail) fields for your inputs:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <?= $form->labelEx($model, 'p_phone', array('class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label')); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <?= $form->textField($model, 'p_phone', array('class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => Yii::t('clients/register', 'Insira o contacto telefónico do empresário.'))); ?>
    </div>
    <?= $form->error($model, 'p_phone'); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: @Criesto Sorry I can not understand what you mean?

Comment: @AndréOliveira Maybe you include jQuery "manually", and CActiveForm "can not now about it" and loads second jQuery. So How you include jQuery script? It's prefer to include like this `Yii::app()->clientScript->registerCoreScript('jquery')`

Comment: I fixed by removing all of my jQuery from main.php, because yii framework add jQuery in assets by itself.

Comment: @AndréOliveira Yii add jQuery itself only if it is necessary: f. e. in page uses any widget which require jQuery (CActiveForm, CGridView, CListView, ....), in other cases yii will not add jQuery, but if you register jQuery (or any script) with component `clientScript` it can not included again

Comment: Its true! Thanks again!